# Using a JWT Token safely in a React/NextJS app

Tags: reactjs, security, next.js, jwt

I understand there is no safe way to store a JWT token on the client side. I have been learning NextJS of late and realized that I can add some server-side code, so the browser will not process it.

When using a separate API that authenticates with a JWT token, is it possible to have the token in the server-side code and store it in memory?

If so, what would the implementation look like in a NextJS app, and have the token used across several components?